# Error when adding centrality_type to xina_plot_all function in XINA package

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, protein-database

I am trying to output some visuals using the `xina_plot_all()` function in the `XINA` package, but when I add a `centrality_type = 'Eigenvector'` to the `xina_plot_all()` I get The following error:

> Error in if (is.na(vertex.color)) { : the condition has length > 1

This produces an error:

```
xina_plot_all(xina_result, clustering_result, centrality_type="Eigenvector")
```

while this does not:

```
xina_plot_all(xina_result, clustering_result)
```

I've tried all the different `centrality_type` parameters and they give me the same errors.
I've restarted from scratch to end up with the same error.